# unable bring footer down in wagtail and in Django html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, wagtail, web-development-server

In Django, if the footer renders correctly on sub-pages but not on the main page, you should examine the main page template and related files. Check for potential issues in the HTML structure, template blocks Verify that the main page correctly extends the base template and includes the footer within the appropriate block. Additionally, inspect any conditional logic or specific settings in the footer.html file that may affect its rendering. Ensure consistency in the template hierarchy and investigate any page-specific configurations that might impact the footer display. By addressing these aspects, you can troubleshoot and resolve the discrepancy in footer rendering.

```
<section class="py-4 mt-lg-5 mt-0" style='background-color: #814EBF; background-image: url("{% static 'images/contact-overlay.png' %}");'>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 text-lg-left text-center">
                <h2 class="h2 cc-contact-footer-h2">
                    Global CTA Title
                </h2>
                <p class="cc-contact-footer-p mb-0">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam laboriosam consequatur saepe.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-lg-right text-center">
                <a href="@todo" class="btn btn-light btn-lg mt-lg-0 mt-3">
                    @todo
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="bg-dark py-4 text-light text-md-left text-center cc-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class=" row mx-lg-n3">
            <div class="px-lg-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="cc-footer-title">Links</div>
                {% for i in "123" %}
                <a class="cc-footer-link-lg d-block" href="@todo">
                    Link #{{i}}
                </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="px-lg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="cc-footer-title">Contact Us</div>
                <!-- @todo: Add contact information -->
            </div>
            <div class="px-lg-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="cc-footer-title">Hours</div>
                <!-- @todo: Add hours information -->
            </div>
            <div class="px-lg-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <a href="@todo" class="cc-footer-social-icon">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/facebook.svg' %}" alt="Facebook">
                </a>
                <a href="@todo" class="cc-footer-social-icon">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/twitter.svg' %}" alt="Twitter">
                </a>
                <a href="@todo" class="cc-footer-social-icon">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/instagram.svg' %}" alt="Ingtagram">
                </a>
                <a href="@todo" class="cc-footer-social-icon">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/youtube.svg' %}" alt="YouTube">
                </a>
                <div class="cc-footer-copy">&copy; {% now "Y" %} ReadySpace</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

the default base.html, you've included the template designation for footer.html. This suggests a foundational template structure with shared elements. The term "default" implies its broad usage. Despite this inclusion, there are issues with the footer rendering correctly on the main page.

Confirm that the main page extends base.html and integrates the footer within the designated block, addressing any discrepancies. This approach aims to maintain a consistent and modular structure in your Django project.

this is the base.html

````html
{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailuserbar %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
            {% block title %}
                {% if page.seo_title %}{{ page.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ page.title }}{% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block title_suffix %}
                {% wagtail_site as current_site %}
                {% if current_site and current_site.site_name %}- {{ current_site.site_name }}{% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        {% if page.search_description %}
            <meta name="description" content="{{ page.search_description }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        {# Force all links in the live preview panel to be opened in a new tab #}
        {% if request.in_preview_panel %}
            <base target="_blank">
        {% endif %}

        {# Global stylesheets #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">

        {% block extra_css %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% wagtailuserbar %}

        {% include "includes/header.html" %}

        {% block banner %}{% endblock %}

        <main id="content" class="container my-4" role="main">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </main>

        {% include "includes/footer.html" %}

        {# Global javascript #}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"></script>

        {% block extra_js %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra javascript #}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>```




   
and the server is running fine with zero error

first see this image in sub page i am getting the normal result
[sub page with normal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR4fl.png)


now look at this as it is my main page and the footer rendering is somewhere breaking in only in front main page

[the breaking footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1v38.jpg)

i am expecting to get my footer at the bottom
````